# how to hide an external table when there is no data in internal table in BIRT?

Tags: birt

I have two tables one inside the other. When there are no detail rows in the inner table i am making it invisible. but i am not able to make the external table invisible.

In detail My inner table heading row and footer is visible even when there are no detail rows so i made the table visibility to true when no detail rows. But i am not able to make the external table invisible with the same logic. it is because even though the inner table is invisible the detail and footer is there so when i say no detail rows no visibility  it is not working. so how can i hide the external table when the internal table is invisible?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. Why should the external table be invisible at all if the inner table contains no data? The only thing which makes sense to me is to hide the outer table if EVERY inner table is empty - note that there's one inner table for each detail row of the outer table.

Comment: No sir. There is only one inner table. The inner table is inside the Detail row of external table. Due to some reason we have structured that way. So the external table and the inner table both should not display when there is no data in the inner table. So kindly help me solving this.

Comment: There is one instance of the inner table per instance of the outer table's detail row. Or do you know for sure that your outer table's dataset will return at most one row?

Comment: actually the outer most table will have at lease one row even if the inner table does not have any data because the inner table footer and header will be present in the outer tables detail row.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: yes the outer table dataset returns one row at least

Answer (score 0):

I would try Binding the data set to the external table and making an aggregation that counts the number of rows in the data set.

- Click on the **Table**
- go to **Binding** in the **Property Editor**
- click **Add Aggregation**

I called the Column Binding Name `RowCount` and set the Function to `COUNT`. Set the Expression to one of the columns from your dataset that you have included in the binding. In my case, I set Expression to `row["columnname"]`.

- Click on **your table**.
- go to **Visibility** in the **Property Editor**.
- check **Hide Element** and **set the Expression to**:

`row["RowCount"]==0 || row["RowCount"]==null`

The element will only display when the `RowCount` aggregation counts more than `1` row in your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was to create a function that counts the records that meet the desired criterion, in my case `select count(*) from my_table where user_id = id`.

Then I inserted this function as a detail component that gets the count based on the selected table record.

Then I used the result of the count as a visibility rule. `count > 0`. this way I can hide the tables that return empty.

Using this trick is possible to hide the secondary table but the count details component will be still there, if you want to hide it you have to put it in a flexbox component. then in the visibility rules you an access you flexbox component and include the rule `count > 0`